# Determine width of a milticolumn cell

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularx, calculations, width

I am attempting to draw a rectangle within a multicolumn, and would like it to span the width of the cell and be consistant with a similar rectangle drawn in a standard cell. I am struggling to determine the correct length of the cell.

Ultimately I would like to be able to insert a 'text box' in each cell of the table and have the width and height automatically fill the space

My MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcolumntype{H}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

\newcommand{\tskip}{&}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\tr}{ O{\hline} O{1mm} }{%
    \tabularnewline[#2]#1
}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\td}{ s O{1} m }{%
    \IfBooleanTF#1%
    {\multicolumn{#2}{X}{#3}\tskip}
    {\multicolumn{#2}{X|}{#3}\tskip}
}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\tf}{ s O{1} m }{%
    \IfBooleanTF#1%
    {\multicolumn{1}{X}{\multirow{#2}{*}{#3}}\tskip}
    {\multicolumn{1}{X|}{\multirow{#2}{*}{#3}}\tskip}
}

\newcommand{\textbox}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [anchor=south west, fill=white,inner sep=1pt] at (0,0.5) {{\scriptsize\scshape#1}};
        \fill [anchor=south west, lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X X X X X H }%
    \hline
    \td[3]{\textbox{Foo}} \td{\textbox{Number 2}} \td*{Bah} \tr[]
    \hline
    \td{bah}    \td{bah} \td[2]{bah} \td*{bah}          \tr
    \tf[2]{foo} \td{foo} \td{foo}    \td{foo} \td*{foo} \tr[\cline{2-5}]
    \td[1]{}    \td{foo} \td{foo}    \td{foo} \td*{foo} \tr
    \td{foo}    \td{foo} \td{foo}    \td{foo} \td*{foo} \tr[]
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The red arrow shows how i would like the box to expand.
[image: Example table]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tabularx` stores the width of X columns in `\TX@col@width`.  Use it to calculate the width of 3 X columns plus 4 `\tabcolsep`'s.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}

\newcolumntype{H}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

\newcommand{\tskip}{&}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\tr}{ O{\hline} O{1mm} }{%
    \tabularnewline[#2]#1
}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\td}{ s O{1} m }{%
    \IfBooleanTF#1%
    {\multicolumn{#2}{X}{#3}\tskip}
    {\multicolumn{#2}{X|}{#3}\tskip}
}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\tf}{ s O{1} m }{%
    \IfBooleanTF#1%
    {\multicolumn{1}{X}{\multirow{#2}{*}{#3}}\tskip}
    {\multicolumn{1}{X|}{\multirow{#2}{*}{#3}}\tskip}
}

\newcommand{\textbox}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [anchor=south west, fill=white,inner sep=1pt] at (0,0.5) {{\scriptsize\scshape#1}};
        \fill [anchor=south west, lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\makeatletter 
\newcommand\mywidth{\TX@col@width}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X X X X X H }%
  \hline
  \td[3]{\textbox{Foo}} \td{\textbox{Number 2}} \td*{Bah} \tr[]
  \hline
  \td{bah}    \td{bah} \td[2]{bah} \td*{bah}          \tr
  \tf[2]{foo} \td{foo} \td{foo}    \td{foo} \td*{foo} \tr[\cline{2-5}]
  \td[1]{}    \td{foo} \td{foo}    \td{foo} \td*{foo} \tr
  \td{foo}    \td{foo} \td{foo}    \td{foo} \td*{foo} \tr[]
  \hline
\end{tabularx} \\[5pt]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X X X X X H }%
  \multicolumn{3}{l}{%
    \colorbox{blue}{%
      \parbox[t]{\dimexpr 3\mywidth+4\tabcolsep\relax}{FOO}%
    }%
  }\\
  \hline
  \td[3]{\textbox{Foo}} \td{\textbox{Number 2}} \td*{Bah} \tr[]
  \hline
  \td{bah}    \td{bah} \td[2]{bah} \td*{bah}          \tr
  \tf[2]{foo} \td{foo} \td{foo}    \td{foo} \td*{foo} \tr[\cline{2-5}]
  \td[1]{}    \td{foo} \td{foo}    \td{foo} \td*{foo} \tr
  \td{foo}    \td{foo} \td{foo}    \td{foo} \td*{foo} \tr[]
  \hline
\end{tabularx} 

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you, that is great! How do I format the \dimexpr such that it calculates ( #1 * \mywidth + (#1 - 1) * \tabcolsep) ?

Comment: `\dimexpr #1\mywidth + \numexpr(#1*2-2)\relax\tabcolsep\relax`.  You have to guard the number type with `\numexpr ...\relax`.  Check also the eTeX manual, section _3.5 Expressions_.

Comment: @ArashEsbati `\dimexpr\mywidth*#1+\tabcolsep*(#1*2-2)\relax` is simpler; an integer factor after a `<dimen>` is interpreted as if it was inside `\numexpr`.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for your hint.  I missed this in the manual which states: a term of type _t_ consists of a factor of that type, optionally multiplied and/or divided by numeric factors; (page 8),